# Proving independence relationship

Tags: independence, beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be continuous positive random variables satisfying $X_1+X_2+X_3<1$ and the following independence relations
$$\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}\perp \!\!\!\perp \frac{X_3}{1-X_1-X_2}~ and$$
$$\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_3}\perp \!\!\!\perp \frac{X_2}{1-X_1-X_3}.$$

Can we prove the following? 
$$\frac{X_i}{1-\sum_{j\neq i}X_j}\perp\!\!\!\perp\{X_j,j\neq i\},\forall i\in\{1,2,3\}.$$
I think the converse should be true, but not sure whether the statement itself is true.